# Commandline-arguments from Explorer splitted at every whitespace

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line-arguments

I noticed a very strange problem with my program. When I try to open a file from explorer, located in a different drive than C, the argument my program recieves is a chopped-up mess!

Here's an example:

If I want to open the file "E:\Downloads\This song has whitespaces in its name.mp3" in the Explorer window (doubleclicking a file), the commandline argument array would look something like this:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

1. E:\Downloads\
2. This
3. song
4. has
5. whitespaces
6. in
7. its
8. name
9. .mp3

Instead of getting the whole thing in one array-entry.
I've scratched my head about this for some time now. But I cannot understand why it's happening. 
Does anyone know the fix?
Thank you.

EDIT:

To explain in more detail what's going on:

I have an Explorer Window opened, and I try to double-click the file which should start my program, and add the file as a commandline-argument.

[image]

If the file contains a whitespace " ", the argument received when my program starts is what I wrote earlier - The path gets split at every whitespace.

My program subscribes to the WPF-event "Loaded", and I simply try to get an array

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Comment: It may be good idea to show how you register your program to open files... As 
sora0419 pointed out you likely missing quotes somewhere...

Comment: I guess `located in a different drive than C` is not a necessary prerequisite for this issue.

Comment: @kennyzx The weird thing is that it only happens when I try to open files located outside of the C-drive.

Comment: interesting, nevertheless, follow [Best Practices for File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-`Always Wrap Expanding Strings in Quotation Marks`. If you do that in registry, Explorer can do the right job.

Comment: @kynnyzx This seems like it can be the solution to my problem. I'll edit the way I've registered my program and get back to you guys, hopefully with a working solution.

Answer (score 3):

Command line arguments are separated by whitespace, that's why when you only put that string in as argument, it will be parsed into multiple arguments.
You shoule use quote to handle it.

When you pass in the command line arguments, put the whole filename in quotes.

Comment: Yes. This I know. But why does Explorer (the window you click files in), not give the arguments wrapped in quotationmarks, which is leading to this issuse?

Comment: @Tokfrans That is just how Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); works, it parses your command line arguments by space and the output is just as expected. You might want to explain in detail about what you did and what you're trying to do.